# PKPaymentAuthorizationController didSelectShippingAddress not called when shippingContact is set on the PKPaymentRequest

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I have a flow in my app where the user fills out a shipping address, so there's an address in my UserDefaults that I use to create a `PKContact` and set the `PKPaymentRequest`'s `shippingContact`. That address may not be one associated with a card already in Apple Pay.

I noticed when the `shippingContact` is set, `PKAuthorizationController`'s `PKPaymentAuthorizationController paymentAuthorizationCoordinator:didSelectShippingAddress:handler` doesn't get called. However when I don't set the `shippingContact`, that method *does* get called.

Any idea why this is? Thanks